# replacing all occurrences of a space character

Tags: text, replace, mootools

I am looking for a solution to replace spaces (non breaking space).
This is what I have attempted:

```
     var text = this.get('text').toLowerCase().replace(' ','');
```

But it did not work as expected and does not replace all spaces.
I am using MooTools if it is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mootools replace only replaces the first instance unless you use regex with a global modifier. Try this instead.

```
var text = this.get('text').toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,'');
```